# Add Pivot Table to Existing Worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, pivot-table

Using vb.net I can successfully create an Excel pivot table in a new worksheet, but when i try to create the same pivot table below my data set within the same worksheet it fails to create the pivot table. Code below shows the working code and the non-working code. What am i missing.

```
 ' Adding pivot table to new worksheet works fine
    With xlBook
        .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
    End With
    xlBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:="Orders Table!R1C1:R26C19", _
                              Version:=Excel.XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Sheet3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1")
    xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    xlSheet.Cells(3, 1).Select()

    ' Adding pivot table to existing "Orders Table" worksheet FAILS
    xlBook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:="Orders Table!R1C1:R26C19", _
                              Version:=Excel.XlPivotTableVersionList.xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Orders Table!R30C1", TableName:="PivotTable1")
    xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Orders Table")
    xlSheet.Cells(30, 1).Select()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most likely reason for this problem is that you're trying to add pivot from another sheet than the target.